# Docker tomcat WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml]

Tags: tomcat, docker, root

I have a slightly complicated setup. I first built and ran a tomcat docker container as root. I had mounted server.xml (as I had custom configuration). It ran fine and served our traffic for months.

I then decided not to run it as root and created a user to run the docker container. I removed the previous docker container, including the docker tomcat image. And I built a new image and ran the tomcat container with the new user using --user $(id -u ). The server.xml is mounted, the file is owned by the new user I have created. However, the tomcat container wouldn't start. I see the error message below with no exception or stack trace:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat <br>
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat <br>
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp<br>
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre<br>
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar<br>
tomcat WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from >[/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml]<br>
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.<br>
```

Comment: can you check if the mentioned server.ml exists and your user has the access rights to read it?

Comment: Yes, server.xml exists and it is owned by the user who is running the Docker. When there is not history of having run the docker container as root, things work fine (I do that in another machine and it works fine there). On this machine however, the container fails to load, even after removing the image.